Why does the Select Field trigger my Modal even when the placeholder is selected?
Description
I'm working with a Chakra UI Select field that opens a modal when an option is selected. The modal header displays the text of the selected option. However, when I select the placeholder from the Select box, it also triggers the modal and displays an empty string "" in the ModalHeader.
Is it normal behavior for onChange to be called when the placeholder is selected? If so, what's the best way to prevent the modal from opening when the placeholder is chosen?
Link to Reproduction
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/6s5h46
Steps to reproduce
Go to https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/6s5h46
Click on Select box
Select any option
Close the modal
Click on the Select box again
Select the placeholder
Chakra UI Version
2.6.1
Browser
Chrome 128.0.6613.113
Operating System
macOS
Additional Information
None
I tried conditional rendering of the modal (ie. opening the modal only when the selected option is the placeholder/ the value of the selected option is "").
  handleChange = (event) => {
    if (event.target.value) {
      setSelected(event.target.value);
      onOpen();
    }
  };

I want to avoid this however if it is not necessary.

onChange gets called any time the value changes, which includes changing to blank.

Can't reproduce the issue with your code sandbox - selecting the placeholder again, does not show any popup. (Tested in Firefox on Mac.)

@C3roe My aplogies. The temporary worked around in the question body was implemented so the issue did not show up in the sandbox. I have removed it now.

@HenryWoody Do you know if this is the default behavior of the native HTML select element? Or is this something unique to the Chakra UI Select component?

Yes, of course it is default behavior for the select element to fire the change event, when the selected option changes. Even if it should happen to change to an empty string.
